# An algorithm for plotting

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have been working on this problem and I am having trouble solving it. Not sure where to start, can someone help me?

```
int below(Plot p, line l);
int above(Plot p, line l);
line findLine(Plot p, line l)
{
}
```

[image: program]

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @Amadeus.: yep...I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's standard binary search problem.

- Now think what you need to find?

The line`y = k` which divide the plot in 2 equal part (based on number of points).

- What is the range of values `y` can take?

Clearly it would be `-1` to `+1`.

- Can you calculate if a line satisfies the property desired by the problem?

Yes you can. Just check every point of Plot p and then check how many of those points have `y` co-ordinate greater than `k`. As you know total number of points then you will know if the points on two sides of the line are equal.

#### Approach

Suppose you select a line `y=k`. Now at this point you see there are more points above than there is below it. Now you will move upward. And if there is more in downside then you will move downward.

```
double good = -1.0,bad= 1+EPSILON;
for(int iter=0;iter<=100;iter++)
{
    mid = (good+bad)/2.0;
    if(check(P,mid)) // if equally divides it then it's done
       // mid is one answer;
    else if( below(p,mid)<above(p,mid))
       good=mid;
    else 
       bad=mid;
}
```